# Are there any ellipses with known exact circumferences and major and minor axes $a$ and $b$ and $a \neq b$?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, elliptic-integrals

I'm new to the world of ellipses and have come to understand that calculating the exact circumference of an ellipse is not a trivial matter that involves elliptic integrals and elliptic functions.

However, does elliptic integration produce the exact circumference, are they workable? Are there any known and proven exact ellipse measurements out there?

Comment: We can calculate the elliptic integral to arbitrary precision. This seems like a non-question.

Comment: Trivially the ellipse with $a=b=1$ has circumference of $2\pi$.

Comment: @GoodMorningCaptain Thanks I edited the question, what about $a=1$ and $b=2$?

Comment: The exact value of the circumference will be given by an elliptic integral as @ParclyTaxel stated. Decimal approximations of that value can be given by any many integral approximation methods. Just because we don't have an exact decimal expressions or "number" (like $2\pi$) does not mean that there isn't an exact value for the circumference.

Comment: The ellipse with $a=1$ and $b=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ (and therefore eccentricity $\frac12$) has a circumference which we can write in terms of the gamma function, specifically $\Gamma(\frac34)$. But then the gamma function is not very nice, either

Comment: @GoodMorningCaptain I understand. I wanted to confirm that the elliptical integral, which I'll have to learn, and hence the questions, that it does in fact produce a result which is, or can be evaluated as an exact real number, correct?

Comment: I think @MishaLavrov ’s example with $\Gamma(\frac34)$ is as explicit as anybody could ask for.